# Strage filename shown in php include error

Tags: php, error-handling, php-include

I'm getting the following error randomly:

PHP Warning:  include_once(TestSystem.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **À«‘** on line 17

The file TestSystem.php exists and is included (most of the times, which makes this even weirder). The second issue is the reported file "**À«‘**" which should be "index.php". I've tried with include, include_once, require and require_once but I get the same behavior.

Anyone knows why this might happen? Thanks in advance.

Server version: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2013 19:05:08) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

Installed Modules

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
soap
sockets
SPL
SQLite
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled xdebug and everything went back to normal.